# Laravel upgrade failing: box/spout v3.3.0 requires ext-zip * but it is not present

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, redhat

I'm attempting to upgrade a very old (version 5.0) Laravel application to the current version, and I'm getting an error when running composer install because I don't have box/spout.  So I tried composer require box/spout, and got the following:

> Package box/spout has requirements incompatible with your PHP version,
> PHP extensions and Composer version:
> - box/spout v3.3.0 requires ext-zip * but it is not present.

I'm working on RHEL server 7.9, with PHP 8.0.22 and composer 2.3.10.  I ran:

> sudo yum install php80-php-pecl-zip.x86_64

then created a zip.ini file in my /etc/php.d directory with "extension=zip.so" in it, and restarted apache, but I'm still getting the same error.  Is pecl-zip the right package?  I did try "sudo yum install php8.0-zip" but it told me there is n such package.  How do I resolve this dependency?

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with CLI commands. Ensure the module is properly loaded in your config files, and verify by checking the output of `php -m`

Comment: how are you using PHP 8.0 with Laravel 5.0 if PHP 8.0 was not available at that moment and Laravel 6.x started supporting it? I would also ask this on [sf] as this is a server configuration more than code issues

Comment: Did you check whether the extension was properly enabled? Which error are you facing that requires the installation of `box/spout`? If you haven't used it before, why do you need to require it on upgrading your application?

Comment: @matiaslauriti, I'm not using PHP 8.0 with Laravel 5, I'm upgrading to Laravel 9.x.  I was running composer install, and got the box/spout error.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem.  I ran rpm ql php80-php-pecl-zip.x86_64, and discovered that yum installed it in a different directory than PHP was trying to load it from.  I moved the zip.zo file to the right directory, and then the module showed up when I ran php -m.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and fixed it. By running

```
rpm ql php80-php-pecl-zip.x86_64
```

I discovered that yum installed the extension into the `/opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules` directory, while PHP was loading from `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`. I copied over the zip.so file, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: NO, you need php-pecl--zip not php80-php-pecl-zip, for a proper configuration / usage, see the Wizard https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/